# nhibernate weird DuplicateMappingException

Tags: nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
namespace fm.web
{
  public class User
  {
    public static string default_username = "guest";
    public static string default_password = "guest";

    private UserType usertype;

    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Datecreated { get; set; }
    public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType Usertype
    {
      get { return usertype; }
      set { usertype = value; }
    }    
  }
}

namespace fm.web
{
    public class UserType
    {
        public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here are the mapping files

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="fm.web"
                   assembly="fm.web">
  <class name="User" table="[user]">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="id" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Username" />
    <property name="Password" />
    <property name="Datecreated" />
    <many-to-one name="Usertype"
                 class="UserType"
                 column="[type]"
                 cascade="all"
                 lazy="false"
                 />
    <property name="Firstname" />
    <property name="Lastname" />
    <property name="Email" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="fm.web"
                   assembly="fm.web">
  <class name="UserType" table="[user_type]">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="id" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm getting an exception: DuplicateMappingException

Could not compile the mapping document: fm.web.data.User.hbm.xml

Duplicate class/entity mapping User

Is nhibernate always this hard?  Maybe I need a different framework.

Comment: I copied your classes and hbm files into a new NH project. I was able to create the schema and save a user/usertype into the database. Could you show your NH configuration code? Which version of NH are you using? Also make sure that your hbm.xml files are set to embedded resources.

Answer (score 0):

I really think the mappings are fine which leads me to believe that the configuration setup is not quite right.

Please can you check that `BuildSessionFactory` is only called once on application start up.
Also please check that you are not including the mapping files twice as this will also throw this type of error.

Please post your configuration code.

You are correct in thinking that NHibernate is difficult to grasp for new comers espically the session management and mappings. Once you have grasped this then things get easier and are well worth the effort.

Comment: Here's the config: `<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
    type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"
/>
        </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    `

Comment: `<session-factory> <br /><property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property><br /> <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property> <br /><property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property><br /> <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=eiosdb8.si-eios.com,2433;Initial Catalog=fm;User Id=********;Password=********;</property><br> <mapping assembly="fm.web" /><br> </session-factory> <br></hibernate-configuration>`

Comment: Have you stepped through code line by line to make sure BuildSessionFactory is only called once?